# javascript: new date, how to set default year?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a set of dates w/ or wo/ year, like the following:

```
10/1/2010
10/1
1-Oct
1-Oct 2006
Jan 4
Jan 4, 2008
```

When I tried to parse them using new Date(),
for those date that don't have year, I got year as 2001
e.g.

```
a=new Date("Jan 4")
Thu Jan 04 2001 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

I want to parse all the dates. If they have year, use that year(2010, 2006, 2008 in the above dates). otherwise, use 2011

Anyone can help?

Thanks,

Cheng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DateJS](http://datejs.com/) for parsing dates. The `Date` constructor's parser is very limited.